# Property between probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, game-theory, bayesian, bayesian-network

$\textit{Q1:}$ Why the statement below holds? If someone could give the intuition and/or a proof I would appreciate it. (this one is answered already so check $Q2$)

Suppose that $\mathcal{I}=(X,\mu)$ and $\mathcal{J}=(Y,\nu)$ are measurable probability spaces, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ denote the probability distributions over $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Thus, if $\phi:X\to\Delta(Y)$, where $\Delta(Y)$ is the simplex of $Y$, then if the image of $\mu$ by $\phi$ is $\nu$ then it holds
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}\phi(x)(y)=\nu(y)$$

Note that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures s.t. for every $x_i$ such that $\mu(x_i)>0$, then $p(x_i)\in\Delta(X_{-i})$ denotes the conditional probability of $\mu$ given $x_i$ over $X_{-i}$:
$$p(x_i)(x_{-i})=\mu(x_{-i}|x_i)=\frac{\mu(x_{-i},x_{i})}{\mu(x_i)}$$

Also, note that $\mu(x_i)$ stands for $\mu(\{x_i\}\times X_{-i})$.

If $i=\{1,2,3\}$, then $X=X_1\times X_2\times X_3= \{a_1,b_1\}\times\{a_2,b_2\}\times\{a_3,b_3\}$ and $x=(\underbrace{a_1}_{x_1},\underbrace{a_2}_{x_2},\underbrace{a_3}_{x_1})$

$\textit{Q2:}$ In the second part I can not clarify from the notation how are the ex-post and ex-ante probabilities connected with $\phi$, $\mu$, $\nu$ and $p$?

Even furhter, the following probabilities are defined. Let $r$ denote the ex-ante probability and $q$ the ex-post probability, they are defined as follows on $\Delta(Y_{-i})$:

$$r(x_i)(y_{−i})= P_{\phi}(y_{−i}|x_i),\quad\text{and}\quad q(y_i)(y_{−i})= P_{\phi}(y_{−i}|y_i)$$

for $P_{\phi}(x_i,y_i)>0$, where $P_{\phi}(x_i,y_i)=\mu(x_i)\phi_{i}(x_i)(y_i)$
then $r(x_i)$ and $q(y_i)$ are random vectors with values in $\Delta(Y_{-i})$ and $f(y_i|x_i)=\phi_{i}(x_i)(y_i)$ and $r(x_i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x_i)}\phi_{-i}(x_{-i})$

I think that $q(y_i)(y_{−i})=\frac{\nu(y_{-i},y_i)}{\nu(y_i)}$, but what is the formula of $r(x_i)(y_{−i})$ and how it ends up to $r(x_i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x_i)}\phi_{-i}(x_{-i})$

$\textit{Hint:}$ Note that $\phi(x)(y)$ means that if $x$ is drawn according to $\mu$, then $y$ is drawn according to $\nu$ with probability $\phi(x)(y)$ where $\phi(x)$ denotes the probability distribution according to which $y$ is going to drawn in other words $\phi(x)(y)=\phi(y|x)$. I think that this $\phi$ is called transition probability between the two probability meaures.

Comment: Ok someone has voted for the question to close, can you explain why?

Comment: Someone voted to close because the question is unclear, and I agree it is unclear, though I think it can be fixed. Particularly, you wrote an equation involving $\phi$, before introducing $\phi$. Can you explain what $\phi$ is, and what $\phi(x)(y)$ means? The notation is alien, and the hint is not sufficient to clarify.

Comment: Also, what does $\nu(y)$ mean? $\nu$ is a probability measure, so $\nu$ takes sets as input. Does this mean $\nu(\{y\})$?

Comment: Dear @MikeEarnest, before you vote you can ask or explain me that I should change things here. You indeed have an impolite behaviour in many cases.  Let me clarify some things....that I can...as for the alien notation, this is not my notation, but somebody elses notation...so you see what I see

Comment: For what it is worth, I was not the one who voted to close.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I didn't mean to say this for you....however...take a look now and tell me if it is clear...if not, maybe i should try to repost it differently...

Comment: @MikeEarnest we could claim the following, right?

So in other words, if $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution on $X\times Y$ then we could claim that
$$f(x,y)=\mu(x)\phi(y|x)=\nu(y)p(x|y)$$

In other words $f(x,y)$ denotes the the probability induced on $X\times Y$ induced by $\mu$ and the transition probability $\phi$ or by $\nu$ and $p$? Namely, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the marginal probability distributions on $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129853/discussion-between-nav89-and-mike-earnest).

Comment: Ok i updated the question with a little bit more to complete the pazzle. Sorry for bothering and thank everyone in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to go conversly? I mean since you know that $r(x_i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x_i)}\phi_{-i}(x^{-i})=\sum_{x_i}p(x_i)\phi_{-i}(x^{-i})$ and so on... and then think what can this mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the equation $\Bbb E_\mu \phi(x)(y)=\nu(y)$ is just a restatement of the law of total probability. To find the probability of $y$ occuring, that is, to find $\nu(y)$, you sum over all of the ways that $y$ can occur. That is, for each $x\in X$, you take the probability of getting $x$, $\mu(x)$, and multiply by the conditional probability of getting $y$ given $x$, which is $\phi(x)(y)$. The result is
$$
\nu(y)=\sum_{x\in X}\mu(x) \times \phi(x)(y)
$$
But the RHS is of the form $\sum_{x\in X} \mu(x) f(x)$, where $f(x)=\phi(x)(y)$, and this is by definition (or really, by the law of the unconscious statistician), equal to $E_\mu[\phi(x)(y)]$.

In other words, there is nothing really to prove. The equation $\nu(y)=E_\mu \phi(x)(y)$ is just a mathematical translation of the previous statement "The image of $\mu$ by $\phi$ is $\nu$."

Comment: From the way that I see it, no matter if it has something to proove or nothing...it confuses me too much....teh notation. Why not trying to define $\phi(x)(y)$ as $\phi(y|x)$? It is so confusing...

Comment: @Nav89 I agree that $\phi(y|x)$ would be clearer.

Comment: one more question...how is $p(\cdot)$ related with $\phi(\cdot)$....there is a relation, isn't it?

Comment: @Nav89 As far as I can tell, $p$ is the "backwards" version of $\phi$. Whereas $\phi$ tells you the likelihood of each value of $Y$ given the value of $X$, the function $p$ tells you, given $y$, the conditional probability it was produced by each $x$.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful!

Comment: So in other words, if $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution on $X\times Y$ then we could claim that
$$f(x,y)=\mu(x)\phi(y|x)=\nu(y)p(x|y)$$

In other words $f(x,y)$ denotes the the probability induced on $X\times Y$ induced by $\mu$ and the transition probability $\phi$ or by $\nu$ and $p$? Namely, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the marginal probability distributions on $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

Comment: @Nav89 Oh yes, that is a good simple way of describing everything.

Comment: The last comment is a bit too much for me to unpack, and also this comment chain is getting too long. If you have a specific other question, you can post it as a separate question.